# How do you view stored string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void clearscreen()
{
    system("cls");
}

int main()
{
    int b1,b,c;
    char data[20]; 
    int number,a;

    printf("How many data do you want to store  ");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    for(a=1;a<=number;a++)
    {
        printf("Input your data No_%d:       ",a);
        scanf("%s",&data[a]);
    }     
    return 0;
}
```

My question is this: after storing the data, how do you view it? 
For example I store 2 data. nxt is I want to view those 2 data.
can someone give me a sample code.

Comment: You didn't read the answer to your previous question well enough. Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Two important things that don't answer your question: Indices of arrays in most programming languages (including C) start with 0, so it should be `for (a = 0; a < number; a++)`. Second: Your program doesn't prevent any input for `number` that's bigger than 20. But if you use e.g. 100, you're writing out of the bounds of the array, which is very bad. Add a check similar to `if ( number > 20 ) return 1;` in front of the for loop

Comment: I did change it in my program.. it still doesnt work.

Comment: "I did change it": What did you change exactly? There are many flaws in that code as all answers and comments say. Did you correct all of this? "it still doesn't work": What's not working? Is there an error message? What did you use as input?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code compiles, but it it fundamentally wrong: `char` is a type that can store a single character, not an entire string. Therefore, `&data[a]` would point to a substring of a previously used string, each subsequent one overriding parts of previously entered ones.

Unfortunately, string manipulation in C is far more complex than that - you need a 2D array or an array of pointers to do your task correctly:

```
char *data[20];
...
for(a=1;a<=number;a++)
{
    char buf[101];
    printf("Input your data No_%d:       ",a);
    scanf("%100s", buf); // 100-char limit, no ampersand!
    data[a] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buf)+1));
    strcpy(data[a], buf);
}
```

Now you are ready to print:

```
for(a=1;a<=number;a++)
{
    printf("Your data No_%d: is %s\n",a, data[a]);
}
```

Finally, you must free the data that you have allocated:

```
for(a=1;a<=number;a++)
{
    free(data[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't quite correct. You are declaring a character array of length 20, i.e. a string of length 20. In your scanf, you are then writing to that from *offset* `a`. What you need to do is to delcare a 2D array of type char, then read into the correct char array, see this as an example:

```
char[20][20] data;

for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++)
    scanf("%s", &data[i][0]);
```

Also, in your loop, change `a=1` to `a=0`. If not, you will loop for `number-1` times. This is because, assuming `number=2`, on the first loop, the test (`a<number`) will succeed. On the second, `a` will be incremented to 2, then the test will fail because `a` is not less than `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array of strings so that each read goes into a separate string.  There are multiple other clean-ups in this code — removing unused variables, checking that inputs succeeded, validating input, echoing data as it is entered (a debugging technique), echoing data after it is entered (another debugging technique — but you usually use just one), fixing the call to `scanf()` because it doesn't expect a pointer to an array, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[20][20]; 
    int number = -1,a;

    printf("How many data do you want to store (1-20) ");
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1 || number > 20 || number <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number: %d\n", number);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (a=0; a < number; a++)
    {
        printf("Input your data No_%d:       ",a+1);
        if (scanf("%19s", data[a]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Oops: failed to read anything\n");
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("%2d: %s\n", a+1, data[a]);
    }

    for (a = 0; a < number; a++)
        printf("Check %2d: %s\n", a+1, data[a]);

    return 0;
}
```